# Give admin consent for app non-interactively as a partner with delegated admin privileges

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant, azure-app-registration

I want to fetch data via Microsoft Graph API (Client Credential Flow) from several customer tenants.
Therefore, I have a multi-tenant app registered in my tenant.
At the moment, I have to give consent for that app in each tenant manually(!). I do so by navigating to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/adminconsent?client_id={appId}". Then signing in with my partner delegated admin account and giving consent. Everything interactively.
When I did this, my app can access the data via Microsoft Graph API in that tenant.
But this is very tedious to do for a bunch of tenants.

Is there a way to do that automatically in code (C#)?

Answer (score 1):

As a partner with delegated administration privileges, you can use the Partner Center API to grant admin consent for your app in the customer tenant:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/partner-center/developer/control-panel-vendor-apis

An example of the API payload body is described here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/developer/gdap-and-secure-application-model#consent-api

For example, to grant the Microsoft Graph delegated permissions *User.Read*, and *Application.Read.All*, the API request would look something like this:

```http
POST https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers/{customer_id}/applicationconsents
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "applicationId": "{your-app-id}",
    "applicationGrants": [
        {
            "enterpriseApplicationId":"00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "scope":"User.Read"
        },
        {
            "enterpriseApplicationId":"00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "scope":"Application.Read.All"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where:

- `{customer_id}` is the tenant ID of the target customer tenant.
- `{your-app-id}` is the app ID (aka client ID) of your app (which is both the app you're using the make this API request, and the app which you'd be granting access to in the target customer's tenant).
- `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is the app ID for Microsoft Graph. If you were granting access for some other API, you'd use that API's app ID.

Some things to keep in mind:

- Your app must call this Partner Center API on behalf of a user (i.e. delegated access) in the context of the *partner* tenant. (The target customer tenant is a parameter of the API request, but the token used should be issued from partner tenant.)
- When calling this API, the signed-in user must be part of the group of users that are granted delegated admin privileges at the target customer tenant.
- To call this API, the privileges granted in the customer tenant to the signed-in user must include the permission to grant consent for these delegated permissions (e.g. Application Administrator, Global Administrator, or a custom directory role with sufficient privileges).
- The Partner Center API cannot be used to grant app roles (application permissions) in the customer tenant. If you need to grant app roles in the customer tenant, you'd need to follow a two-step approach:

  - Step 1: Use the Partner Center API to grant your app delegated permissions in the customer tenant (as described above).
  - Step 2: Using the delegated permissions granted in the previous step, use Microsoft Graph (in customer's tenant) to [assign app roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to your app (or perhaps a different app, depending on the scenario).
  - The signed-in user on behalf of who the API calls are made will of course need to have sufficient privileges in the target customer tenant for granting the app roles (application permissions) in question. For Microsoft Graph app roles, this requires Global Administrator, Privileged Role Administrator, or a custom directory role with the necessary permissions.
  - **IMPORTANT**: The steps above will grant your app permanent privileged access in the target customer's tenant. Even if the customer has granted you sufficient delegated admin privileges, you must only do this if it is explicitly part of your agreement with the target customer, and you have a clear understanding with the customer of what happens to this privilege when you delegated administrator relationship ends.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The thing is that we are only indirect resellers. Excuse me, I was unaware the importance to mention that. I saw that according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/developer/get-started "API access to Partner Center for indirect resellers isn't supported."